# Get Text Starting From Last Occurrence of Certain Substring Leading to Match

Tags: regex

Given a long string that generally follows this syntax:

```
/C=US/foo=bar/var=1/CN=JONES.FRED.R.0123456789:xxj31ZMTZzkVA 
/C=US/foo=pop/var=2/CN=BLAKE.DAPHNE.P.1234567890:xxj31ZMTZzkVA
/C=US/foo=bit/var=8/CN=BINKLEY.VELMA.W.2345678901:xxj31ZMTZzkVA
/C=US/foo=hat/var=17/CN=ROGERS.SHAGGY.N.3456789012:xxj31ZMTZzkVA
/C=US/foo=jam/var=39/CN=DOO.SCOOBY.D.4567890123:xxj31ZMTZzkVA
```

I want to capture what follows the previous occurrence of "/C=US/" that leads up to the last name + dot + first name that follows "CN=", and finally the text that precedes the colon (:). The last name, dot, and first name are not hard-coded but rather passed in from a variable.

For example, given "DOO.SCOOBY", I want to extract this text:

```
/C=US/foo=jam/var=39/CN=DOO.SCOOBY.D.4567890123
```

Here is the Regex I am using:

```
(?<=\/C=US\/)(.*?)(?=DOO.SCOOBY)+(.*?)+:
```

The problem is, it extracts **ALL** of the text preceding the match of "DOO.SCOOBY" to the colon, except for the very first "/C=US/". So, I nearly get the entire string back. It's also important to note there are **no linebreaks or spaces** in this string; it is all bunched together. How can I get text that only goes back as far as the previous "/C=US/"? I've searched plenty on regexes and specifically this scenario, but can't seem to find anything. It looks like I need to implement the positive lookbehind correctly.

Comment: Please see [this example](https://regex101.com/r/gmtcsR/1). Where are you using the regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The example you provided extracted only what was after "CN=", rather than "/C=US/". I'm actually reading a file and returning any matches for a first name and last name that a user searches for. For this example, I tweaked the syntax a little to avoid leaking any sensitive data, but the same logic would still apply.

Comment: You do not have to use `CN=`. See `(?<=/C=US/.*?)DOO\.SCOOBY[^:]*` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmtcsR/2). What is your code?

Comment: It appears the returned string is the same as last time. That's what regex101 is highlighting, anyway.

Comment: And what do you want to get? The substring from the start of string? `/C=US/.*?DOO\.SCOOBY[^:]*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmtcsR/3))? Then why did you use lookarounds in your regex?

Comment: Yes, that is the string I want. I actually may have left out an important detail in my problem. When reading the file, it seems the text gets bunched together without any line breaks. So, in this link https://regex101.com/r/FzQvHw/1, with no space between the text, the returned string is about the same as before. That's when I started looking into positive lookbehinds. But what I could do is parse the file contents so that after it is read, the string includes line breaks. That could make my situation a lot easier, but a regex on the current string is still feasible, I'm sure.

Comment: So you need `\/C=US\/(?:(?!\/C=US\/).)*?DOO\.SCOOBY[^:]*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/FzQvHw/2)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\/C=US\/(?:(?!\/C=US\/).)*?DOO\.SCOOBY[^:]*
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FzQvHw/2).

*Details*:

- `\/C=US\/` - a `/C=US/` string
- `(?:(?!\/C=US\/).)*?` - any single char, other than line break chars, zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that does not start a `/C=US/` substring
- `DOO\.SCOOBY` - a `DOO.SCOOBY` string
- `[^:]*` - zero or more chars other than `:`.